# Java Access Token PKCS11 Not found Provider

Tags: java, security, digital-signature, pkcs#11

Hello I'm trying to access the keystore from my smartcard in Java. And I'm using the following code..

I'm using the Pkcs11 implementation of OpenSc http://www.opensc-project.org/opensc

**File windows.cnf** =

```
name=dnie
library=C:\WINDOWS\system32\opensc-pkcs11.dll
```

**Java Code** =

```
String configName = "windows.cnf"
 String PIN = "####";
 Provider p = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(configName);
 Security.addProvider(p);
 KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11", "SunPKCS11-dnie");  =)(= 
 char[] pin = PIN.toCharArray();
 keyStore.load(null, pin);
```

When the execution goes by the line with **=)(=**  throws me the following exception

```
java.security.KeyStoreException: PKCS11 not found

    at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:635)
    at ObtenerDatos.LeerDatos(ObtenerDatos.java:52)
    at ObtenerDatos.obtenerNombre(ObtenerDatos.java:19)
    at main.main(main.java:27)
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: PKCS11 for provider SunPKCS11-dnie
        at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getService(GetInstance.java:70)
        at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:190)
        at java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:662)
        at java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:632)
```

I think the problem is "SunPKCS11-dnie", but I don't know to put there. I had tried with a lot of combinations...

Anyone can help me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure the problem is the name. It looks correct. [ColinD's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833989/java-access-token-pkcs11-not-found-provider/4834023#4834023) to pass the `Provider` instance should rule it out as a problem.

I am guessing that the problem is with the PKCS11 support. Like, you don't have a card in your reader, or the native code cannot access the reader. Have you tried using this driver in conjunction with some "known good" software, like Firefox or Thunderbird's security modules?

Comment: I found the .dll for my smartCard reader (asepkcs.dll). And I tried again with the same code (with the @ColinD's recomendations) and Works! 
So the problem was the .dll . You have to have the correct dll for you device.

Answer (score 8):

I was also getting the error as below:

`Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: PKCS11 for provider SunPKCS11`

I am running the application from a jar through bat file.

I bat file I replaced the code : `java - jar sign.jar` 
with code:  `java -Djava.security.debug=sunpkcs11,pkcs11 -jar SigningUtility.jar`

And it solved the issue.

Comment: I don't see how giving the debug options would resolve this issue. Possibly you called this from a different working directory?

Comment: Adding the `-Djava.security.debug=sunpkcs11,pkcs11` also worked for me (without any other changes to working dir or java executable -- using java 8 BTW).

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just pass the `Provider` directly as the second argument to [KeyStore.getInstance(String, Provider)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html#getInstance%28java.lang.String,%20java.security.Provider%29). In your code you'd just do:

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11", p);
```

Comment: Good suggestion. This is how I do it. Although the name looks correct in the code, it would be good to eliminate naming as a problem.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? 
maybe, 
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11", "opensc") ??

Comment: @oracleruiz: `KeyStore` has an overload of `getInstance` that takes a `Provider` directly as the second argument: [KeyStore.getInstance(String, Provider)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html#getInstance%28java.lang.String,%20java.security.Provider%29). See my edit, though @erickson is right that it could be something else in which case that would still fail.

Comment: @oracleruiz: Yeah. Looking at it further, this exception is pretty much exactly what I see when there's no card in the reader.

Answer (score -1):

Try the below code:

```
// Create instance of SunPKCS11 provider
String pkcs11Config = "name=eToken\nlibrary=C:\\Windows\\System32\\eps2003csp11.dll";
java.io.ByteArrayInputStream pkcs11ConfigStream = new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(pkcs11Config.getBytes());
sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 providerPKCS11 = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(pkcs11ConfigStream);
java.security.Security.addProvider(providerPKCS11);

// Get provider KeyStore and login with PIN
String pin = "12345678";
java.security.KeyStore keyStore = java.security.KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11", providerPKCS11);
keyStore.load(null, pin.toCharArray());
```

it is working fine for me.